# Drupal CKEditor: CKEDITOR.replace not adding instance in Drupal.wysiwyg.instances

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am working in Drupal 7 and CKEditor. I am loading some textfields in ajax and replacing CKEditor using `CKEDITOR.replace()` function. CKEditor is successfully replaced with textarea, but i can't able to add media files to CKEditor.

I got an error saying that,

```
drupal.wysiwyg.instances[this.instanceid] is undefined
```

So I tried,

```
Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[new_instance] = Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[old_instance];
Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[new_instance].field = new_instance;
```

Now I can able to add Audio, Video, document files which will show as Links in CKEditor. But now I can't able to add image file which will be displaying as image in CKEditor.

And another one issue is, when I am assigning a field value like this,

```
Drupal.wysiwyg.instances[new_instance].field = new_instance;
```

but it is not assigning my field name here.

Am I doing it right way? If it is wrong, tell me the way to attach the new CKEditor to the `Drupal.wysiwyg.instances`.